# Not able to create local server profile on RAD 6.0

Tags: rad

I need to create a new server profile within RAD 6.0.0 The problem i am facing is that i am unable to see "Websphere v6.0 local server profile creation" section after going to Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Websphere.

Could it be the problem with installation as i got JVM terminated,Exit code=1 error upon installation and i get this error again i start RAD. As of now I am able to get away with it by starting eclipse and not RAD ie by going to RAD installation Directory -> eclipse ->

Additional details -

Operating system - Windows7 (64 bit)

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Update - I am able to get away with JVM terminated problem by changing RAD compatible type to Windows 7 but still i am not able to see "Websphere v6.0 local server profile" section.

Comment: See if this is of help http://www.buggybread.com/2013/03/cant-see-server-profile-for-local.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is already profile created in some other machine. Better get the following folder and replace on your machine.

\runtimes\base_v6\properties

or One can refer the following IBM article to create a new profile

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftpro_instancessaappserv.html